# After a period of time address researching doesn't generate results. java.io.IOException: Service not Available

Tags: android, search, location, reverse-geocoding

I have a big problem.

I wrote this code that get Address informations relating to coordinates:

```
public static Address getAddressFromLocation(Context c, Location location){
        Address address = null;
        if(location!=null){
            final Double addrLat=location.getLatitude();
            final Double addrLng=location.getLongitude();
            final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(c, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(getRound(addrLat, 15), getRound(addrLng, 15), 1);
                  if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                      Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                      Locale locale = returnedAddress.getLocale();
                      address = new Address(locale);
                      address = returnedAddress;

                        if(address.getLocality()==null || address.getLocality().equals("")){
                            int line = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex()-1;
                            if(line<0)line=0;
                            address.setLocality(address.getAddressLine(line));
                        }

                  }else{
                      address=null;
                  }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                  address=null;
            }     
        }else{
            address=null;
        }
        return address;
    }
```

After performing the search several times I get no Address and I don't understand why.

I can restart the device or do a search after a period of time and I'm not able to find any Address anymore.

The error is:

```
java.io.IOException: Service not Available
```

Which is the problem?

Comment: Is this method called by an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Yes,this method is called by an AsyncTask.

Comment: I've had my share of difficulties with `AsyncTasks`, like the `doInBackground()` not being called after 5 calls to that same `AsyncTask`. You might have this same problem.

Comment: If you're doing too many requests Google might be blocking/throttling your IP for a while: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits

Comment: Ok. But this "while" is too long. It is possible that after a lot of days I can't read the address?

Comment: The exception is:
java.io.IOException: Service not Available